# Android APK invalid? Didn't find class "AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my App on my SmartPhone:

```
Didn't find class "munyul.game.android02.android.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList
```

Due to HD issues, I was forced into rebuilding my machine and setting up my developed environment again. After a lot of messing around, I have the following installed and working:

- Java 1.8
- Eclipse Neon
- libGDX
- Android SDK Manager

The Android App in question was almost finished, but now that goal seems like a long way off :(

I used libGDX to create a *new* project, and then I copied the old code into the new project - this is where things got **messy**.

I had to fix several errors caused by changes in libGDX, which was easy. I then also had to fix several errors caused by changes to Google Services, this was not easy! I eventually read about the new `m2repository` folder, then I searched for and found the class files needed (play-services-ads, -base, -basement, -games and -plus, inside `.aar` files), placed all the `classes.jar` files into their own directory within the android/libs project folder, finally adding references to them from within Eclipse - now everything compiles and looks good (should these .jar files be checked for export? - **see edit**)

Finally, I had to make one more change; the old project/code was created with a package: `munyul.game.android02.android`, but the new only had `munyul.game.android02`, I added the missing package to the new and also updated the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (maybe this is what went wrong!?).

I've checked the code and manifest and everything looks correct, but when I run the App it instantly crashes with the above mentioned error.

Also, I've checked the Order and Exports for the android project, the boxes that should be checked are.

Anyone know what else I could try?

EDIT:

As a test, I checked the Google Services JAR's for Export, and now I'm getting a different error:

```
Could not find class 'android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method 
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>
```

I'm starting to think that my error lies with how I resolved my Google Services issues - is there a better way of linking the missing classes? Somehow adding them via Gradle?

EDIT #2:

I migrated the entire project to Android Studio - now the APK installs and runs correctly on all my devices.

Honestly, I would have prefered to stick with Eclipse, but it seems like that is no longer an option - HTH

Answer (score 2):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for the correct application class (or none if you are not overriding.)  The `AndroidLauncher` is part of the "instant run" feature available in Android Studio and is automatically injected by gradle into the manifest file.

Eclipse is no longer a supported development toolchain - you'll want to do your migration to Android Studio (or IntelliJ) sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to the question. I'm not going to mark this answer as correct, as your Manifest response didn't help - I've tried variations without success.

Comment: I have however given you a +1 for your Android Studio comment - not the answer I was looking for, but it is now the solution I am trying ... I've migrated the Desktop sub-project, just need to get the Android sub-project working, then hopefully all will be working again...

Comment: Interesting. You'd have to provide more file contents to help determine what is going on, though. Thanks for the +1.